# IE8 or IE9 - Support for multiple file seclection for upload without Flash and HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, dojo

I have gone through several Javascript libraries from DOJO to Knockout. And I am aware of flash based solutions such as Uploadify or others such as Plupload.

I am looking for a solution to upload multiple files using IE preferably using IE8 or IE 9. The key thing is the ability to **select multiple files** rather than using one by one files to upload. Using javascript, I can upload multiple files by selecting one file at a time.

It seems IE does not allow to select multiple files. So I am more looking for a drag and Drop solution to drop multiple files and upload them in a single go.

Again no flash, no applets, no siverlight and no HTML5.

Are you aware of such a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=Drag%20and%20Drop) Internet Explorer 9 and below do not support `dataTransfer.files`.
Unfortunately the only alternative it's a one-by-one selection or some Flash plugin.